# Python interp1d vs. UnivariateSpline

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to port some MatLab code over to Scipy, and I've tried two different functions from scipy.interpolate, [interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) and [UnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline).  The interp1d results match the interp1d MatLab function, but the UnivariateSpline numbers come out different - and in some cases very different.

```
f = interp1d(row1,row2,kind='cubic',bounds_error=False,fill_value=numpy.max(row2))
return  f(interp)

f = UnivariateSpline(row1,row2,k=3,s=0)
return f(interp)
```

Could anyone offer any insight?  My x vals aren't equally spaced, although I'm not sure why that would matter.

Answer (score 19):

I just ran into the same issue.

## Short answer

Use [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline) instead:

```
f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(row1, row2)
return f(interp)
```

## Long answer

[UnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) is a 'one-dimensional smoothing spline fit to a given set of data points' whereas [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline) is a 'one-dimensional interpolating spline for a given set of data points'. The former smoothes the data whereas the latter is a more conventional interpolation method and reproduces the results expected from [interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d). The figure below illustrates the difference.

[image: Comparison of interpolation functions]

The code to reproduce the figure is shown below.

```
import scipy.interpolate as ip

#Define independent variable
sparse = linspace(0, 2 * pi, num = 20)
dense = linspace(0, 2 * pi, num = 200)

#Define function and calculate dependent variable
f = lambda x: sin(x) + 2
fsparse = f(sparse)
fdense = f(dense)

ax = subplot(2, 1, 1)

#Plot the sparse samples and the true function
plot(sparse, fsparse, label = 'Sparse samples', linestyle = 'None', marker = 'o')
plot(dense, fdense, label = 'True function')

#Plot the different interpolation results
interpolate = ip.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(sparse, fsparse)
plot(dense, interpolate(dense), label = 'InterpolatedUnivariateSpline', linewidth = 2)

smoothing = ip.UnivariateSpline(sparse, fsparse)
plot(dense, smoothing(dense), label = 'UnivariateSpline', color = 'k', linewidth = 2)

ip1d = ip.interp1d(sparse, fsparse, kind = 'cubic')
plot(dense, ip1d(dense), label = 'interp1d')

ylim(.9, 3.3)

legend(loc = 'upper right', frameon = False)

ylabel('f(x)')

#Plot the fractional error
subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex = ax)

plot(dense, smoothing(dense) / fdense - 1, label = 'UnivariateSpline')
plot(dense, interpolate(dense) / fdense - 1, label = 'InterpolatedUnivariateSpline')
plot(dense, ip1d(dense) / fdense - 1, label = 'interp1d')

ylabel('Fractional error')
xlabel('x')
ylim(-.1,.15)

legend(loc = 'upper left', frameon = False)

tight_layout()
```

Comment: The document you link to notes that InterpolatedUnivariateSpline is "Equivalent to UnivariateSpline with s=0", which is what he was using.

Answer (score 16):

The reason why the results are different (but both likely correct) is that the interpolation routines used by `UnivariateSpline` and `interp1d` are different.

- `interp1d` constructs a smooth B-spline using the `x`-points you gave to it as knots
- `UnivariateSpline` is based on FITPACK, which also constructs a smooth B-spline. However, FITPACK tries to choose *new* knots for the spline, to fit the data better (probably to minimize chi^2 plus some penalty for curvature, or something similar). You can find out what knot points it used via `g.get_knots()`.

So the reason why you get different results is that the interpolation algorithm is different. If you want B-splines with knots at data points, use `interp1d` or `splmake`. If you want what FITPACK does, use `UnivariateSpline`. In the limit of dense data, both methods give same results, but when data is sparse, you may get different results.

(How do I know all this: I read the code :-)

Comment: LSQUnivariateSpline lets you specify the knots, so you could specify them as equal to the input? But it still doesn't seem to produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me,

```
from scipy import allclose, linspace
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, UnivariateSpline

from numpy.random import normal

from pylab import plot, show

n = 2**5

x = linspace(0,3,n)
y = (2*x**2 + 3*x + 1) + normal(0.0,2.0,n)

i = interp1d(x,y,kind=3)
u = UnivariateSpline(x,y,k=3,s=0)

m = 2**4

t = linspace(1,2,m)

plot(x,y,'r,')
plot(t,i(t),'b')
plot(t,u(t),'g')

print allclose(i(t),u(t)) # evaluates to True

show()
```

This gives me,

[image]

Comment: I just ran the following:


    `from pylab import *`
    `from scipy.interpolate import *`

    `x=[3,5,6,8,10]`
    `y=sin(x)`
    `z=r_[3:4:.1]`

    `f=interp1d(x,y,kind=3)`
    `f1=f(z)`

    `g=UnivariateSpline(x,y,k=3,s=0)`
    `g1=g(z)`

    `print f1-g1`

And it returns:

[  1.13797860e-15  -2.14227085e-03  -3.88345765e-03  -5.25282403e-03
  -6.27963364e-03  -6.99315013e-03  -7.42263713e-03  -7.59735830e-03
  -7.54657727e-03  -7.29955769e-03]

Comment: @Timothy Dees: Ah, I see the problem. Remember that interpolation is a process of approximating a function with some other function; as you sample more and more points from the original function, so convergence should improve. Try your example with more `x` points. Your example works for me if I sample around 2**6 points. `linspace()` makes it easy to generate an evenly spaced sample.

Answer (score 0):

> UnivariateSpline: A ***more recent***
>   wrapper of the FITPACK routines.

this might explain the slightly different values? (I also experienced that UnivariateSpline is much faster than interp1d.)

Comment: It's definitely much faster, which is why I want to use it, but it gives very different numbers from MatLab, so I've been forced into the slower interp1d function.